# Intellij 2020.1.2: why does scratch file give different output?

Tags: intellij-idea, scratch-file

I sometimes use scratch files to check something, but now suddenly it started to give 'old output' when I reached scratch_11. I think it didn't coop with the 11 and executed the scratch_1 instead.

What i wrote was a simple system.out.println("FHDS"); but it keeps returning 100.0.

- Started from the class file, within class, run configuration
- Threw away all scratch files
- rebooted Intellij
- Tried it in an other project and there it works just fine!

Anyone happended to experience the same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: does it help if you invalidate caches (File | Invalidate cache)?

Comment: Nope, it didn't.